# SnackBar in Flutter doesn't become transparent on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter

I run into a problem I got this `Snackbar` and I want it to look like pciture1, it works fine in android but not in iOS.

In iOS, it looks like picture2.

I couldn't find out what causes this weird difference in iOS.

So my question is: **How can I achieve the Design of picture1 in iOS?**

Note: I don't want to use FlutterToast or Flushbar if possible.

**Picture 1:**
[image]

**Picture 2:**
[image]

The `Snackbar` Code:

```
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class SnackBarCustom {

  SnackBar snackBarCustom(final String title, final double height, final double width, final int maxLines) {
    return SnackBar(
      elevation: 1000,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
      behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      content: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: width * 0.11,
          vertical: height * 0.06,
        ),
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: width * 0.0075),
          height: height * 0.06,
          width: width,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(height * 0.0374),
            color: const Color(0xFF555555).withOpacity(0.75),
          ),
          child: AutoSizeText(
            title,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              fontSize: width * 0.32,
              color: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
              letterSpacing: 0.8,
            ),
            minFontSize: 5,
            maxFontSize: 14,
            maxLines: maxLines,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you sad, you don't want to use fluttertoast if possible, but I think,
their is no easy way to achieve what you trying without it.

So I advise you to use fluttertoast, it works on IOS and Android and its easy to use.

For your desired Design you need to use the Toast which requires context.

**The Code:**

```
showToast(final FToast fToast, final String title, final double height, final double width, final int maxLines) {
    Widget toast = Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: width * 0.015),
      height: height * 0.06,
      width: width * 0.55,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(height * 0.0374),
        color: const Color(0xFF555555).withOpacity(0.75),
      ),
      child: AutoSizeText(
        title,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
          fontSize: width * 0.32,
          color: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
          letterSpacing: 0.8,
          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
        ),
        minFontSize: 5,
        maxFontSize: 14,
        maxLines: maxLines,
      ),
    );


    fToast.showToast(
      child: toast,
      gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
      toastDuration: Duration(seconds: 2),
    );

  }
```

You also need to have a FToast instance, which has to be used **this way:**

```
 FToast fToast;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fToast = FToast();
    fToast.init(context);
  }
```

For more Information, have a look at: [fluttertoast](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast)